# what is an uninitialized pointer pointing at, and can I detect this state in fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran

```
system:
Mac OSX 15.something
gfortran 10.2.0
```

consider the following program and its output

```
program main
  character(len=256), target :: c
  character(len=256), pointer :: p
  c = "foo bar"
  print *, associated(p)
  ! print *, p  -> gives segfault of course
  p => c
  print *, associated(p)
  print *, trim(p)
  nullify(p)
  print *, associated(p)
end program main
```

```
>>> ./a.out
T
T
foo bar
F
```

Why does p show that it is associated in the first check?  What is it associated to? Is it possible to detect such a pointer that has not been initialized but still shows that it is associated?